# lakeFS Docker build fails

Tags: docker, go, lakefs

I am trying to get started with a "local" data processing ecosystem which includes Presto, Spark, Hive. lakeFS and a few other.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:

  lakefs:
    image: treeverse/lakefs:latest
    container_name: lakefs
    depends_on:
      - minio-setup
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - LAKEFS_DATABASE_TYPE=local
      - LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_TYPE=s3
      - LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_FORCE_PATH_STYLE=true
      - LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_ENDPOINT=http://minio:9000
      - LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=minioadmin
      - LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=minioadmin
      - LAKEFS_AUTH_ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY=some random secret string
      - LAKEFS_STATS_ENABLED
      - LAKEFS_LOGGING_LEVEL
      - LAKECTL_CREDENTIALS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
      - LAKECTL_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
      - LAKECTL_SERVER_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:8000
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    command:
        - |
          lakefs setup --local-settings --user-name docker --access-key-id AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE --secret-access-key wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY || true
          lakefs run --local-settings &
          wait-for -t 60 lakefs:8000 -- lakectl repo create lakefs://example s3://example || true
          wait

  minio-setup:
    image: minio/mc
    container_name: minio-setup
    environment:
        - MC_HOST_lakefs=http://minioadmin:minioadmin@minio:9000
    depends_on:
      - minio
    command: ["mb", "lakefs/example"]

  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    entrypoint: ["minio", "server", "/data", "--console-address", ":9001"]

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: metastore_db

  hive-metastore:
    build: hive
    container_name: hive
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"
    environment:
      - DB_URI=mariadb:3306
    volumes:
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/apache-hive-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536

  hive-server:
    build: hive
    container_name: hiveserver2
    ports:
      - "10001:10000"
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore
    environment:
      - DB_URI=mariadb:3306
    volumes:
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/apache-hive-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    entrypoint: [
      "wait-for-it", "-t", "60", "hive:9083", "--",
      "hive", "--service", "hiveserver2", "--hiveconf", "hive.root.logger=INFO,console"]

  hive-client:
    build: hive
    profiles: ["client"]
    entrypoint: ["beeline", "-u", "jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10000"]

  trino:
    image: trinodb/trino:358
    container_name: trino
    volumes:
      - ./etc/s3.properties:/etc/trino/catalog/s3.properties
    ports:
      - "48080:8080"

  trino-client:
    image: trinodb/trino:358
    profiles: ["client"]
    entrypoint: ["trino", "--server", "trino:8080", "--catalog", "s3", "--schema", "default"]

  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    container_name: spark
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hive-site.xml

  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    ports:
      - "8081"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    volumes:
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hive-site.xml

  spark-submit:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    profiles: ["client"]
    entrypoint: /opt/bitnami/spark/bin/spark-submit
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - ./:/local
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hive-site.xml

  spark-sql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    profiles: ["client"]
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - ./:/local
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hive-site.xml
    command: ["spark-sql", "--master", "spark://spark:7077"]


  spark-thrift:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    container_name: spark-thrift
    command: ["bash","-c", "/opt/bitnami/entrypoint.sh"]
    depends_on:
      - spark
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
    volumes:
      - ./etc/spark-thrift-entrypoint.sh:/opt/bitnami/entrypoint.sh
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hive-site.xml


  create-dbt-schema-main:
    image: trinodb/trino:358
    profiles: ["client"]
    entrypoint: ["trino", "--server", "trino:8080", "--catalog", "s3", "--execute", "drop schema if exists dbt_main  ;create schema dbt_main with (location = 's3://example/main/dbt' )"]

  dbt:
    build: dbt
    profiles: ["client"]
    volumes:
      - ./dbt/dbt-project:/usr/app
      - ./dbt/profiles.yml:/root/.dbt/profiles.yml
    entrypoint: dbt

  notebook:
    # To login to jupyter notebook, use password:lakefs
    build: jupyter
    container_name: notebook
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./etc/jupyter_notebook_config.py:/home/jovyan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
      - ./etc/hive-site.xml:/usr/local/spark/conf/hive-site.xml

networks:
  default:
    name: bagel
```

when I run "docker compose up" I get this error:

```
=> ERROR [build 7/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg     GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64      0.4s
 => CACHED [lakefs 2/8] RUN apk add -U --no-cache ca-certificates                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [lakefs 3/8] RUN apk add netcat-openbsd                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [lakefs 4/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [lakefs 5/8] COPY ./scripts/wait-for ./                                                                                               0.0s
------                                                                                                                                                
 > [build 7/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build     --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg     GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64     go build -ldflags "-X github.com/treeverse/lakefs/pkg/version.Version=dev" -o lakefs ./cmd/lakefs:
#0 0.407 webui/content.go:7:12: pattern dist: no matching files found
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c GOOS=$TARGETOS GOARCH=$TARGETARCH     go build -ldflags "-X github.com/treeverse/lakefs/pkg/version.Version=${VERSION}" -o lakefs ./cmd/lakefs]: exit code: 1
```

My OS is:

```
Linux B460MDS3HACY1 5.15.0-58-generic #64~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 16:42:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My go is:

```
go version go1.16.7 linux/amd64
```

What should I do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange - the docker-compose uses an image and it should just pull it and not try to build a docker image.
Can you verify that the working directoy holds your docker-compose?
You can also verify that you are using the latest images by `docker-compose pull` before calling `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Looks like changing the working directory did the trick. thanks!